# What model should I use to represent an array of values in bluetooth mesh?

Tags: bluetooth, mesh

I'm building bluetooth mesh using NRF PCA10040 boards and Zephyr. I would like to publish an array of between 0 and 10, 16 bit values as a response to single GET message. What server model should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the on-off model, there is a get-callback function, which will be called when receiving a message with GET-opcode. This function uses the "access_model_reply" function to reply to the present state of light, and the tx-state-value is actually an 8bits-value.

Try modifying the get_cb function in main.c and status_msg struct in generic_onoff_message.h, then you can transfer the array you want to the source address of received get the message.

I tried transferring 6bytes message instead on-off message with set function in the client model.

> Notice: any message larger than 6bytes with being segmented, a 64bytes messages will take about 2 seconds to be transferred.